# Python parse XML with unusual tag name (atom:link)

Tags: python, xml

I'm trying to parse out `href` from the below XML.  There are multiple `workspace` tags, below I just show one.

```
<workspaces>
  <workspace>
    <name>practice</name>
    <atom:link xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" rel="alternate" href="https://www.my-geoserver.com/geoserver/rest/workspaces/practice.xml" type="application/xml"/>
  </workspace>
</workspaces>
```

The above comes from a `requests.get` command using the requests library:

```
myUrl = 'https://www.my-geoserver.com/geoserver/rest/workspaces'
headers = {'Accept': 'text/xml'}
resp = requests.get(myUrl,auth=('admin','password'),headers=headers)
```

If I search for 'workspace' I get objects returned:

```
lst = tree.findall('workspace')
print(lst)
```

Which results in:

```
[<Element 'workspace' at 0x039E70F0>, <Element 'workspace' at 0x039E71B0>, <Element 'workspace' at 0x039E7240>]
```

Ok fine, but how do I get the text href out of the string, I have tried:

```
lst = tree.findall('atom')
lst = tree.findall('atom:link')
lst = tree.findall('workspace/atom:link')
```

But none of them work to isolate the tag, in fact the last one creates an error

> SyntaxError: prefix 'atom' not found in prefix map

How can I get all instances of href with these tag names?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For others who find this problem, the part before the colon (in this case `atom`) is known as a namespace, and causes the issue here.  The solution is quite simple:

```
myUrl = 'https://www.my-geoserver.com/geoserver/rest/workspaces'
headers = {'Accept': 'text/xml'}
resp = requests.get(myUrl,auth=('admin','my_password'),headers=headers)
stuff = resp.text
to_parse=BeautifulSoup(stuff, "xml")

for item in to_parse.find_all("atom:link"):
    print(item)
```

Thanks to Saket Mittal for pointing me towards the BeautifulSoup library.  The key was using `xml` as an argument in the BeautifulSoup function.  Using `lxml` simply won't parse the namespace properly and ignores them.

Answer (score 2):

Easy solution i found:

```
>>> y=BeautifulSoup(x)
>>> y
<workspaces>
<workspace>
<name>practice</name>
<atom:link xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" rel="alternate" href="https://www.my-geoserver.com/geoserver/rest/workspaces/practice.xml" type="application/xml">
</atom:link></workspace>
</workspaces>
>>> c = y.workspaces.workspace.findAll("atom:link")
>>> c
[<atom:link xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" rel="alternate" href="https://www.my-geoserver.com/geoserver/rest/workspaces/practice.xml" type="application/xml">
</atom:link>]
>>>
```

Comment: I get simple [] as my output, it must have something to do with the format of resp.text which is just text as far as I can tell.  It works if I use y.workspaces.findAll("workspace"), but that isn't what I'm after.